# Access to LocaleStorage from Middleware in Universal mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Such a situation:
As far as I understand, to access LocaleStorage from Middleware in Universal mode
is impossible (at least by default.)

Question:
Are there any solutions (modules possible) to solve such problems?
(if yes - what can you recommend first of all?)

Comment: you cant its serverside. why do you need localstorage is it possible to solve it with cookies instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localstorage in nuxt middleware is not accesible as it is used for client side only. However We can use cookies and can also access vuex store in milleware as
1.Using cookie

```
export default (context) => {
    if (!context.app.context.app.$cookies.get('loginState')) {
        return context.redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

2.Accessing store in middleware

```
export default function({ store, redirect }) {
  if (!store.getters.GET_LOGIN_STATE) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

Here are possible solutions put your data in store or cookie

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store something on the client side that is not gonna getting deleted after page refresh then use cookies. You can access cookies in the middleware:

The Nuxt context contains the property `req` and the cookies are attached to the header

```
export default function ({ req, store}) {
   let cookie = require('cookie');
   let cookies = req.headers.cookie;
   let parsedCookies = cookie.parse(cookies);
   console.log(parsedCookies);
}
```

In this example i use the package `cookie` to parse the cookies `npm i cookie`